# How to break PumpWaitingMessages for every one hour and check for any unread mails

Tags: python, subprocess, win32com, pythoncom

I want to break PumpWaitingMessages for every one hour and check for any unread mails and I tried with following code.

However, if I increase `time.time()-starttime>10` then my outlook is hanging and not able to progress, Sometimes I am even able to get following error:

This is related to [How to continuously monitor a new mail in outlook and unread mails of a specific folder in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695160/how-to-continuously-monitor-a-new-mail-in-outlook-and-unread-mails-of-a-specific)

```
 pTraceback (most recent call last):
 File "final.py", line 94, in <module>
 outlook_open=processExists('OUTLOOK.EXE')
 File "final.py", line 68, in processExists
 print('process "%s" is running!' % processname)
 IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Please check the code and help me to resolve this.

```
 import win32com.client
 import ctypes # for the VM_QUIT to stop PumpMessage()
 import pythoncom
 import re
 import time
 import os
 import subprocess
 import pyodbc

 class Handler_Class(object):

    def __init__(self):
      # First action to do when using the class in the DispatchWithEvents     
      outlook=self.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
      inbox=outlook.Folders['mymail@gmail.com'].Folders['Inbox']
      messages = inbox.Items
      print "checking Unread mails"
      # Check for unread emails when starting the event   
      for message in messages:
         if message.UnRead:
           print message.Subject.encode("utf-8") # Or whatever code you wish to execute.
           message.UnRead=False

    def OnQuit(self):
       # To stop PumpMessages() when Outlook Quit
       # Note: Not sure it works when disconnecting!!
       print "Inside handler onQuit"
       ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)

    def OnNewMailEx(self, receivedItemsIDs):
      # RecrivedItemIDs is a collection of mail IDs separated by a ",".
      # You know, sometimes more than 1 mail is received at the same moment.
      for ID in receivedItemsIDs.split(","):
          mail = self.Session.GetItemFromID(ID)
          subject = mail.Subject
          print subject.encode("utf-8")
          mail.UnRead=False
          try: 
            command = re.search(r"%(.*?)%", subject).group(1)
            print command # Or whatever code you wish to execute.
          except:
            pass

 # Function to check if outlook is open
 def processExists(processname):
   tlcall = 'TASKLIST', '/V', '/FI', 'imagename eq %s' % processname
   # shell=True hides the shell window, stdout to PIPE enables
   # communicate() to get the tasklist command result
   tlproc = subprocess.Popen(tlcall, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   # trimming it to the actual lines with information
   tlout = tlproc.communicate()[0].strip().split('\r\n')
   # if TASKLIST returns single line without processname: it's not running
   if len(tlout) > 1 and processname in tlout[-1]:
      if "Not Responding" in tlout[2]:
         print('process "%s" is not responding' % processname)
         os.system("taskkill /f /im  outlook.exe")
         return False
      print('process "%s" is running!' % processname)
      return True
   else:
      print('process "%s" is NOT running!' % processname)
      return False

# Loop 
while True:
  try:
     outlook_open = processExists('OUTLOOK.EXE') 
  except: 
     outlook_open = False
  #If outlook opened then it will start the DispatchWithEvents
  if outlook_open == True:
     outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class)
     while True:
         starttime=time.time()
         while (int(time.time()-starttime)<10):
             pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()    
         ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)     
         outlook_open=processExists('OUTLOOK.EXE')
         if outlook_open == False:
             break
         #Handler_Class.__init__(outlook)
         # To not check all the time (should increase 10 depending on your needs)
  if outlook_open == False:
     print "outlook not opened"
     os.startfile("outlook")
  time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, first if you do `time.time()-starttime>10` it's normal that outlook is hanging as you don't go in this `while` loop and then your code performed `outlook_open=processExists('OUTLOOK.EXE')` all the time. In your code it's `int(time.time()-starttime)<10` and it works fine, you just have to do `int(time.time()-starttime)<3600` to check for an hour

Comment: your question about break `PumpWaitingMessages`, you mean that you don't exist the loop `while (int(time.time()-starttime)<10)` if you quit yourself Outlook?

Comment: when i keep `int(time.time()-starttime)<3600` my outlook and code both are hanging after some time and get an error "IOError: [Errno 0] Error" when  i press enter

Comment: I am able to exit the loop .. my question is 

Let say i am monitor outlook for new mails using `PumpWaitingMessages` .. after one hour i want to check for any unread mails and then process it. Once done it should check again for new mails  using `PumpWaitingMessages` ... this process should go on in a loop ...

Comment: this part where `#Handler_Class.__init__(outlook) ` in my code ... need to be replace with  some logic so that it calls `_init_ ` to check again for unread mails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to check your unread email at the place of `#Handler_Class.__init__(outlook)` just do:

```
win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class)
```

(no need of assignment really). But I don't see the point in your code because the rest of the time you are monitoring for incoming email with `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()` and can do the same thing.

For your problem with outlook is hanging, not sure what is the problem, I try to run it myself few hours and it works. Maybe to reduce some CPU use (this might be your problem depending on your computer), you can try to add a `time.sleep()` in your loop while such as:

```
while (int(time.time()-starttime)<100):
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

And while I'm answering, I don't think that both `ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)` you have in your code are necessary anymore with `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()`, they were used to stop `pythoncom.PumpMessages()`. I had no difference in behavior with or without.

Let me know